# Как вставить новые записи в таблицу с первичным ключом если нет доступа к последовательности?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть таблица `STREETS (ID, NAME)`, где `ID` - первичный ключ.

Нужно вставлять в нее данные, но доступа к последовательности (*sequence*) у меня нет. Для создания функций и т.п., прав тоже не хватает.

Mогу ли я каким-либо образом прямо в запросе, возможно, используя переменные, получать максимальный `ID` таблицы и вставлять запись с `ID+1`?

В MySQL это прекрасно решалось бы так:

```
set @i = (SELECT MAX(Id) + 1 FROM Streets );
INSERT INTO Streets (Id, Name)
  VALUES (@i, 'Некоторое имя');
```

Есть ли возможность сделать это в Oracle 10g в рамках серии запросов из программы-клиента?

Comment: Вы можете это сделать используя `PLSQL` или триггер, но вообще говоря, это подход плохой. Используйте `sequence`, они для этого и созданы. А если вам не разрешают, то требуйте более настойчиво

Comment: странное решение в MySQL, проще было бы в один запрос `INSERT INTO Streets (Id, Name) SELECT MAX(Id) + 1, 'Некоторое имя' FROM Streets` и в оракле оно то же отработает. НО так делать нельзя, надо получать доступ к секвенсу. Ведь если вы вставите новые номера, а из секвенса их получать не будете, то секвенс продолжит помнить старый номер и обычная вставка где нибудь в программе получит из секвенса один из ID которые вы уже создали без его использования !

Comment: @Mike, спасибо, сам не додумался вызывать селект вместо VALUES. 
Знаю, что нельзя. Слава богу, Идентификаторы записей разделены по пользовательским группам (у каждой группы есть свое уникальное число, а ИД записи составляется из этого числа + несколько разрядов, образующих уникальность). Решение не мое, бороться тоже не можем.
Мы долго бились за права на объекты БД, но отдел, заведующий этим, не поддается. Приходится выкручиваться по-всякому.

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте завел собственный секвенс со строго заданным диапазоном и возможно с нестандартным шагом что бы он выдавал id из разрешенного вам диапазона. (Ну и с chache 1 что бы номера не терять по пусту, если их мало)

Comment: "Мы долго бились за права на объекты БД, но отдел, заведующий этим, не поддается." - Административные проблемы лучше решать административными методами. Вы сейчас сделаете велосипед, а когда что-нибудь сломается, шишки будут ваши, потому что велосипед тоже ваш.

Comment: Речь судя по всему о продуктивной среде. Раз вам не дали  права на объекты БД, значит вам попросту запретили эти  объекты изменять. Ваш вопрос не имеет практического применения, скорее всего у вас и прав на изменение Streets нет. Если есть, их просто забыли забрать. Попробуйте провести изменения в тестовой среде и если возникнут затруднения, обрашайтесь с новыми вопросами.

Answer (score 3):

Если нет прав, кроме как делать запросы и изменения в таблице, то будет уместно такое решение - выполняйте анонимный блок вместо простого запроса на изменение:

```
create table Streets (Id, Name) as
    select 999900077, 'name abc' from dual
/
begin 
    lock table Streets in exclusive mode;  
    insert into Streets (Id, Name) 
        select max (Id) + 1, 'new name' from Streets;
end;
/
select * from Streets;

        ID NAME    
---------- --------
 999900077 name abc
 999900078 new name
```

---

PS Если есть увереность, что вставка не может быть осуществленна одновременно из двух и более сессий, то `lock` из блока можно опустить, но следует учесть, что когда говорят:
*Нет, это 100% невозможно*, то один раз в год или два оно почему-то случается.